# ASP.NET - Regular expression to exclude specific characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regex that can accept all letters (A-Z which are case sensitive), numbers (0-9), spaces and most characters.  The field must not accept accented characters (ÁÉÚÍÓ), tabs, or the following characters: backslash (), less than (<), greater than (>), tilde (~), equals (=), double quotes (”) or comma (,)

Any ideas on what sort of regex I would need for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`^([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$`

It will match `foo bar 1234 FOO BAR` but not `foo bar 1234 FOO BAR  dd` or `foo bar 1234 FOO BAR\`

Note: You can then add the *most characters* within the square bracket.

Edit: `foo bar 1234 FOO BAR dd` contains a tab (`\t`) character but it is being shrunken down.

Comment: I have tried it with http://regexpal.com/ and `<`,`>`,`"` and `,` are resulting into a no match.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should the characters you want

```
(?:[^\p{L}\\<>~=",\t]|[A-Za-z])
```

`[]` denotes a character class, there you can put all characters in, that you want to allow

`[^]` denotes a negated character class, all characters inside are not allowed.

So, I don't know a predefined class that contains all letters that are not in A-Z, there fore I would go for an alternation.

The first negated class contains **all** letter in `\p{L}`, and the rest are the other characters you don't want to allow, but since you want to allow `A-Z` and they are also in `\p{L}` you have to allow them again. That is done in the second part (the `|` is an alternation) where I allow `[A-Za-z]`.

So the complete regex should look something like this

```
^(?:[^\p{L}\\<>~=",]|[A-Za-z])+$
```